# Node+React deployment to Heroku: No default language could be detected for this app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, heroku

I am trying to deploy my first Node+React (+MongoDB through Mongoose) application to Heroku, but when running the command `git push heroku master`, I am getting this error:

```
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:             HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

The error indicates that Heroku is unable to recognize the language of my app. I guess it has something to do with my project structure and it looks I'll unfortunately need to re-organize it:

```
/root
  /backend
    - models
    - node_modules
    - ...
    - package-lock.json
    - package.json
  /frontend
    - node_modules
    - public
    - redux
    - ...
    - package-lock.json
    - package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is Heroku doesn't know what the entry point is. I'd recommend separating your `backend` and `frontend` apps into two separate heroku apps - it would simplify a lot. But if you want both in the same Heroku "app" I believe you'll have to setup a central node server in the root, and then direct all calls under `/api` to your backend, and all other calls to your `/frontend` (or however you want to structure that.

[Here's a tutorial on Heroku that seems to walk you through what you're trying to do](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api#source-code-structure)